# Five Images repeatedly display in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing application in which i want display five images in `UITableViewCell`.
I have already develop UITableView with custom cell but i don't know how to display five static images repeatedly in my UITableView

for example,

Cell1 - Image1

Cell2 - Image2

Cell3 - Image3

Cell4 - Image4

cell5 - Image5

cell6 - Image1

cell7 - Image2

... and so on.

Comment: create a array and set multiple image(how many you want).and display in customcell.

Answer (score 2):

by help of modulo(`%`) you can repeat your images.

write below code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of tableView.

```
if(indexPath.row % 5 == 0)
    {
        // cell 1 - set image1
    }
    else if(indexPath.row % 5 == 1)
    {
        // cell 2 - set image2
    }
    else if(indexPath.row % 5 == 2)
    {
        // cell 3 - set image3
    }
    else if(indexPath.row % 5 == 3)
    {
        // cell 4 - set image4
    }
    else
    {
        // cell 5 - set image5
    }
```

after you can adjust it as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks...this works perfect but this solution is very lengthy in case when more than 5 images need to repeat...i'm looking for some solution that works in every aspect.

Comment: @TejasPatel you can refer vadian's answer. he has given solution which is works in every aspect. it might be helps you.

Answer (score 1):

- Create an array of the images

  ```
  NSArray<UIImage *> *imageArray = @[image1, image2, image3, image4, image5];
  ```
- In `cellForRow` assign the image to the `imageView`. The `%` operator performs a division by the length of the array (5) and uses the remainder (in this case 0 - 4) as the array index.

  ```
  cell.imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row % imageArray.count];
  ```